# soap:address location shows hostname instead of DNS url

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

We currently have 2 web services we have written, one is using CXF and the other is just using JAX-WS.

In the vanilla JAX-WS service the soap address looks like this

`<soap:address location="http://server-name:8080/Service"/>`

In the CXF service the soap address looks like this

```
<soap:address location="http://cxfservice.website.com/Service"/>
```

How can I make the JAX-WS service use the DNS url instead of the hostname for the soap address location? (These services are sitting behind a load balancer and if the hostname of the server is used the client cannot resolve the address)

Comment: What do you mean that "the other is just using JAX-WS"? Which framework is providing the JAX-WS service?

Comment: It is just using the JAX-WS annotations for its configuration.  I believe its called Metro.

Answer (score 0):

For the CXF one, you can define the address you want when you define the endpoint. If you're using Spring to configure CXF, that would look something like:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="wsEndpoint"
    address="http://cxfservice.website.com/Service" ...>
    ...
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

For more details and configuration options about how to configure a CXF endpoint, here's a link to the CXF documentation: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html

Comment: The CXF service is configured correctly.  My question was can a JAX-WS(Metro) be configured to use a "proxy?" address?